# adb shell "screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png" failes with "No space left on device", but there is enough space

Tags: android, adb, screen-capture

Did somebody experience and solved such a problem?

We use adb shell screencap command to catch screenshots on Android device:

```
//catch and download screenshot 
adb shell "screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png"
adb pull "/sdcard/screen.png" "tempPictPathName"
//clean
adb shell "rm /sdcard/screen.png"
```

It worked perfectly for quite a long time. For some reason (nothing changed nor in our code, neither on device under test) we began to receive "No space left on device" error when running the same command both from cmd and from code:

```
>adb shell "screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png"
Error opening file: /sdcard/screen.png (No space left on device)
```

We checked, there is enough space on device:

```
$ ls -l /storage/
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2018-12-16 10:35 sdcard -> /storage/emulated/legacy
$su -c df
Filesystem                               Size    Used     Free   Blksize    
/storage/emulated                      930.4M    0.0K   930.4M      4.0K
    /storage/emulated/0                      8.9G    6.1G     2.9G      4.0K
    /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb          8.9G    6.1G     2.9G      4.0K
    /storage/emulated/legacy                 8.9G    6.1G     2.9G      4.0K
    /storage/emulated/legacy/Android/obb     8.9G    6.1G     2.9G      4.0K
```

We tried to change location for .png file with no success:

```
>adb shell "screencap -p /sdcard/Download/screen.png"
Error opening file: /sdcard/Download/screen.png (No space left on device)
>adb shell "screencap -p /storage/sdcard/Download/screen.png"
Error opening file: /storage/sdcard/Download/screen.png (No space left on device)
```

After device was restarted the command `adb shell "screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png"` succeeded but only once. 
When we try to save picture by taking photo by camera - no problem reported

What can cause the "No space" error?

Comment: Have you verified that location `/sdcard/Download/` exists and you have write permissions for that?

Comment: We'd like to continue to use original location /sdcard/screen.png which worked for a long time and still working on all other devices. Our question is how to solve the problem on problematic tester. What can cause the suddenly appeared problem?

Comment: The new devices don't use `/sdcard/` any more, or rarely have SDcards, so I think you can't continue with existing code. Check my answer bellow.

Comment: We followed your advise, /sdcard/ exists and is reachable (as I mentioned, the device didn't change). After some research we found that it looks like some application caught the disk space and didn't release it, also it was not visible by df command. After we uninstalled not used applications, the problem diapered

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the location you are using does not exist.

You can try some of the listed storage locations ie.

```
/storage/emulated                      
/storage/emulated/0
```

So your code should be:

```
//catch and download screenshot 
adb shell "screencap -p /storage/emulated/0/screen.png"
adb pull "/storage/emulated/0/screen.png" "tempPictPathName"
//clean
adb shell "rm /storage/emulated/0/screen.png"
```

In case this not possible you can use the following commands:

```
# open the device shell
adb shell
# find your path in the device
pwd
# list all directories of this location
ls -la
# move into a directory with name dir_name
cd dir_name
# repeat "ls" and "pwd" commands as many times you need for the navigation
# when you find the location you want to put the recoding use again pwd to get the full path
pwd
```

Other alternative can be the use of variable `$EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

```
adb shell "screencap -p $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/screen.png"
```